# Return id of new Item created with POST using ModelSerializer and ModelViewSet in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'd like to get the new `id` as a response after making a `Post` in Django Rest Framework.

*Intended function:* User gets a json response with the hyperlink to the new item created.

POST

```
{
    "label": "BMW M3",
    "price": 5000.00
}
```

Response:

```
 {
        "id-url": "www.website.com/api/products/id/"
    }
```

I am aware this topic been covered in various ways but I am looking for a minimal (but complete) example using a ModelSerializer, I have not be able to find this yet, thus my question.

My model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

My view:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

My urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('products', ProductViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Attempts:

Some references I have attempted.
Here is similar question but the answers does seems incomplete [ex_0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046551/how-to-return-primary-key-as-a-response-when-ever-we-make-a-post-request-using-d)
I can re-create this [ex_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913388/return-custom-response-to-successful-post-request-in-django-rest-framework), but does not give me the id

Comment: What you have got now? How does it look like your model?

Comment: This might help you, [Relationships & Hyperlinked APIs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/)

Comment: thanks, hyperlink is secondary here though, its foremost the id I am looking for (that I will create a hyperlink of), I amended the question to reflect this.

Comment: Why do you say [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046551/how-to-return-primary-key-as-a-response-when-ever-we-make-a-post-request-using-d) looks incomplete? What happens when you try it?

Comment: Hi, adding 'id = serializers.IntegerField(source='pk')' to the serializer does not create the json response with the id. When trying I also get an error, "A valid integer is required." Ideally I am looking for a complete (functional) answer. As a newbie incomplete snippets of code is a bit confusing as much is left out in the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this post: [Get the id of the object recently created Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27760674/10778349) I managed to come up with a potential solution. It seems to work but I am a bit unsure if it is the "best" way or not.

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            product = serializer.save()
            pid = product.id
            product.url = f'http://localhost:8000/api/products/{pid}/'
            data = serializer.data
            data.update({'id-url':product.url}) # attaching key-value to the dictionary
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ProductViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # response.data has everything specified in your serializer; it seems fine to clobber it
        # alternatively, you could add to it: response.data['foo']='baz'
        response.data = {'id-url': f'http://localhost:8000/api/products/{response.data['id']}/'}
        return response
```